'healthy' to mean 'working properly'
Is there an adjective in English which describes a device that works properly?
As opposed to 'broken: damaged not or working properly'.
Is it correct to use the adjective 'healthy'? As in

Is the vacuum cleaner healthy?

It sounds rather strange to me in this sentence. But I've seen it used with car or engine. I was wondering if it's correct to use it with any noun of the sort, and whether it's commonly used.

Is the vacuum cleaner working? You don't need 'properly' except in a reply – 'not properly' if it is not working very well.

@WeatherVane Thanks. So the word healthy isn't a word you'd use in that context, right?

Not for a vacuum cleaner, no. It's sometimes used to describe more complex systems.

A vacuum cleaner might be unhealthy for its user if the dust bag is faulty and it's spewing out carpet mites everywhere :)

@WeatherVane - tell me about it! (long term asthma sufferer).

@MichaelHarvey I love those road sweeper machines that drive around when full and throw it all out of the vent at the top, for the wind to deposit in the places it came from...

@WeatherVane - do you remember the early-2000s US rhetoric (Dubya et al) about 'bringing down the hammer' on 'dirtbag nations'? When I heard 'dirtbag' it always made me think of my parent's 1940s Goblin cylinder vacuum cleaner that had a removable bag that used to get in a deplorable state and needed washing periodically. The machine made an awful noise that terrified the cat. It was one of these

@MichaelHarvey no, but I remember laughing out loud when I realised why the Americans called him 'Dubya'.

The adjective "healthy" is generally not used to describe whether a device, machine, or object is functioning properly. It is more commonly used to describe living things, like people, animals, or plants, to indicate good physical condition or overall well-being. When applied to machines or devices, it can sound odd or awkward, as in your example with the vacuum cleaner.
Instead, common adjectives / phrases to describe a device or machine that is working properly include:

Operational: "Is the vacuum cleaner operational?"
Functional: "Is the vacuum cleaner functional?"
In working order: "Is the vacuum cleaner in working order?"
Working: "Is the vacuum cleaner working?"
Serviceable: "Is the vacuum cleaner serviceable?"

For cars or engines, you might occasionally hear "healthy" to describe an engine that's running well, but even then, it's not as precise as saying the engine is "in good condition" or "running smoothly." The use of "healthy" in this context is more metaphorical and much less common.
In summary, 'healthy' is not generally used to describe machines or devices. More accurate and commonly used terms are "functional," "operational," or "working."

Although "healthy" isn't generally used to describe something like a vacuum cleaner, it doesn't strike me as unnatural at all. I certainly wouldn't treat it as an indicator of a non-native speaker. In fact operational and functional may be more correct but less idiomatic than healthy.

For physical, mechanical items such as vaccuum cleaners, cars etc, it is not common to say they are "healthy". We'd normally say running well, in good working order, and perhaps more formally, performing optimally. There are also some idioms such as "running like clockwork" which are used informally.
However, 'healthy' is commonly used in connection with computer software. Microsoft have a 'PC Health Check' app, and it's common for people to refer to "PC health" or "system health", so it wouldn't be at all unusual to say you have a "healthy computer".
Many other inanimate and abstract things may be referred to as "healthy", such as finances, the economy, relationships, environments etc.
